# Presenting a ModalViewController inside a ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a view which is presented as a modal view controller which takes username and password credentials. I want this view to check the delegate, and if the user hasn't previously set an unlock pin for the app, to then show the change pin view as a modal view controller. This is my code...

```
+(void)presentCredentialsViewController:(UIViewController *)vc{
    CredentialsViewController *cvc = [[CredentialsViewController alloc] init];
    [vc presentModalViewController:cvc animated:FALSE];
}
```

and then in CredentialsViewController

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if([appDelegate.pin isEqualToString: @""]){
        UserPrefsViewController *upvc = [[UserPrefsViewController alloc] init];
        upvc.cancelButton.hidden = true;
        [self presentModalViewController:upvc animated:FALSE];
    }
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. The debugger steps through the code without error, never the less, the second modal view controller isn't displayed.

Comment: what if you put this code in `viewDidAppear`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest checking that your `appDelegate.pin` is blank and not nil.  If it is nil, the if statement would not be satisfied and your second ModalView would not be presented.

You may also want to try the previous suggestion, calling `presentModalViewController` from `viewDidAppear`, or setting a delay if leaving it in `viewDidLoad`.  It is possible that the `CredentialsViewController` is trying to present the second view when it has not yet presented itself.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is being hit and the second PresentModalViewController is executing without error, but it just wasn't displaying. I did try putting the code in ViewDidAppear and a load of other places as well, such as applicationWillBecomeActive etc. Although not actually crashing the code, still none of these approaches would show the view controller. In the end I have opted for this:

```
start with pin of @""
on applicationDidEnterBackground check if pin has been set
if yes
PresentModalViewController: PinViewController
if no
do nothing
```

Bit of a hack but it will do for now. I suppose I should put some sort of notification in somewhere warning that the pin hasn't been set. The suggestion about the delay may possibly work I suppose. I might give it a go in the future. Thanks guys....points up!